# Can this query be shorter? Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Keep in mind that I use sqlite so I can't use stuff like:

```
(SELECT Z1, Z2, Z3, DECODE(Z1, 'x', 1, 0) + DECODE(Z2, 'x', 1, 0) + DECODE(Z3, 'x', 1, 0) test FROM InfoP1)
```

This is my query:

```
 String sql = "SELECT  ID, Nume, Prenume,"
            + "InfoP1.Z1, InfoP1.Z2, InfoP1.Z3, "
            + "SUM(InfoP1.Z1 + InfoP1.Z2 + InfoP1.Z3) AS Total,  "            
            + "(SELECT(((CASE WHEN Z1 = 'x' then 1 else 0 END)"
            + "+ (CASE WHEN Z2 = 'x' then 1 else 0 END)"
            + "+ (CASE WHEN Z3 = 'x' then 1 else 0 END))*8) AS Test),"                                      
            + "FROM InfoAn "
            + "LEFT JOIN InfoP1 ON InfoAn.ID = InfoP1.rowid "
            + "GROUP BY ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, [boolean](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean_datatype) expressions return `0` or `1`, so you can simply drop the decoding:

```
SELECT Z1, Z2, Z3, (Z1 = 'x') + (Z2 = 'x') + (Z3 = 'x') AS test FROM InfoP1
```